# Rails 3.2 - Validations - Redirect To Back with Error

Tags: validation, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need help with error validations/redirects....

If I use `format.html {redirect_to :back, flash: {error: "Oops, something went wrong. Please try again."}` the error message works, but it does not hold the form data so the user needs to re-input and doesn't know which fields were incorrect.

The `format.xml {render :xml => @award.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}` line redirects to back, but it doesn't show any errors.

I would like to see which fields are incorrect, with their validation messages intact.  Please help with syntax.  Thanks in advance!

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @award.save
    format.html { redirect_to(new_award_path, :notice => 'Thank you for your nomination!') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @award, :status => :created, :location => @award }
  else
    format.html {redirect_to :back}
    #format.html {redirect_to :back, flash: {error: "Oops, something went wrong. Please try again."}}
    format.xml {render :xml => @award.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end
```

**UPDATE to include more detail:**

I'm using 2 different forms for this create method.  Each form has a hidden field to set a boolean value, then I do stuff in my controller based on that hidden condition.  If there are errors, I need to redirect to the correct form, hold its values, and show the appropriate error fields.  Something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @award.save
        format.html { redirect_to(new_award_path, :notice => 'Thank you for your nomination!') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @award, :status => :created, :location => @award }
      else
        if boolean_field == true
            format.html { render action: "true_form" }
            format.xml {render :xml => @award.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
        else
            format.html { render action: "false_form" }
            format.xml {render :xml => @award.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity}
        end
      end
end
```

When I try it this way, errors work, but it always goes back to the true_form, even if I started on the false_form.  So, it's like it's ignoring the boolean_field condition... make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is not redirecting when there are errors, but simply rendering the view again.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @award.save
    format.html { redirect_to(new_award_path, notice: 'Thank you for your nomination!') }
    format.xml { render xml: @award, status: :created, location: @award }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.xml { render json: @award.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the problem is, what I forgot to include in my original post, is that I'm using 2 different forms for this create method.  So, I need something that goes back to the form used, which is why I used `redirect_to :back`  I will edit my original post.

Comment: Well, hell - it does work now.  WTF?  I swear, I tried this like 25 times.  Just gotta talk to the mechanics, and the problem goes away!  Thanks!